# date is not null but returns 0000-00-00

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a date field where the value is always "0000-00-00". However, when I explode it to year, month, and day, it outputs right. What could be wrong with my code?

```
<div class="controls" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
   <div id="dpYears1" class="input-append date" data-date="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>">
    <input type="text" id="billing_date" placeholder="Billing Date" name="billing_date" class="span2" value="">
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

And this is how I call it:

```
<td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row->billing_date; ?></td>
```

Comment: 0 is not null in some languages.

Comment: You are not `explode()`ing date. You showing current date.

Comment: you might check your backend. Maybe it's literally returning `0000-00-00` and not null

Comment: use strtotime function it will work

Comment: Show the related PHP code please, I.e. print_r the value of `$row->billing_date;`